# How to login a specific user to selected activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

This app can register 2 main users student and teacher after registering the users they can login if the user is a teacher there will be a toast msg saying teacher if it's a student there will be a toast saying student in the register page student and teacher will selected by a checkbox

this is the code i tried

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_USER + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.NAME + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.PASSWORD + "=?", new String[]{user,pass});
                if(username.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 ||
                        password.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                    toast(MainActivity.this,"All fields are required");
                }
                else if (cursor != null){
                    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                        if(DatabaseHelper.TYPE.equals("Teacher")){
                            toast(MainActivity.this,"Teacher");
                        }
                        else{
                            toast(MainActivity.this,"Student");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        toast(MainActivity.this,"Not Found");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    toast(MainActivity.this,"Error");
                }
            }
        });
```

When i tried to login it always return Student what did i do wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is not much information to analyze but the line:

```
if(DatabaseHelper.TYPE.equals("Teacher")){
```

looks not correct. You need something like :

```
if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TYPE)).equals("Teacher")){
```

if TYPE is the name of column in which you store the string "Teacher".

Comment: I tried this but the app is crashed with this error `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

Comment: TYPE is the column that store the data that return from the checkbox

Comment: this is how the registering process goin on `}else if (db.registeruser(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(),teacher.isChecked() ? "Teacher" : (student.isChecked() ? "Student" : "N/A"))){
                    loginScreen();
                    toast(Register.this,"Successfully Registered Please Login");
                }`

Comment: what do you mean by second line

Comment: just under rawQuery line. check hear https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983528 and hear https://stackoverflow.com/a/12423246. That line is a part of cursor.